# How does open handle context management?

Tags: python, file, with-statement, contextmanager

The python built-ins `open`, and `file` work with context managers in a way that I don't quite understand.

It is to my understanding that `open` will create a `file`.  `file` implements the context-manager methods `__enter__` and `__exit__`.  I would initially expect `__enter__` to implement the actual opening of the file descriptor.

However, using `open` outside of a `with` block will return a `file` which is already open.  So, it appears either `file.__init__` or `open` is actually opening the file descriptor, and as far as I can tell `file.__enter__` isn't doing anything.  Or maybe `file.__init__`/`open` calls `file.__enter__` directly?

First question:

What is the execution-flow of the `open` built-in?  What does `open` handle, what does `file.__init__` handle, and what does `file.__enter__` handle?  How does this work when re-using one `file` object for multiple cycles of opening/closing the file? How is this different from re-using other contextmanager objects for multiple context-cycles?

Second question:

Objects such as `file` objects have a setup steps and teardown steps.  The setup occurs in `__init__` , and the tear-down occurs in either `close` or `__exit__`.

Is this a good design pattern?  Should this design pattern be implemented for custom functions/context managers?

Comment: Python is open source, which means you can see how it's implemented  by looking at it [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/branches) and answer your own question(s).

Comment: I think https://github.com/python/cpython is preferred nowadays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in _pyio.py (a pure-Python implementation of the io module) you find the following code in class IOBase:

```
### Context manager ###

def __enter__(self):  # That's a forward reference
    """Context management protocol.  Returns self (an instance of IOBase)."""
    self._checkClosed()
    return self

def __exit__(self, *args):
    """Context management protocol.  Calls close()"""
    self.close()
```

This contains the answers to most of your questions.  The important thing to understand is that the context manager's function is to insure that you close the file when you are done with it.  It does this simply by calling the `close` function, which saves you the trouble of doing so.

What does `file.__enter__` handle?  Nothing.  It simply returns to you the file object that was the result of the call to the built-in function open().

How does this work when using one file object for multiple cycles of opening and closing the file?  The context manager is not very useful for that purpose, since you must explicitly open the file each time.

Is this a good design pattern?  Yes, because it reduces the amount of code you have to write, it's easy to read and understand.

Should this pattern be implemented for custom functions/context managers?  Any time you have an object that needs to be cleaned up, or has usage that involves some type of open/close concept, you should consider this pattern.  The standard library has many other examples.

Answer (score 1):

**For Question 1**

In CPython, **open()** does nothing but creating a **file** object, which the underlying C type is **PyFileObject**; See source code in [bltinmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1504) and [fileobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/fileobject.c)

```
static PyObject *
builtin_open(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds)
{
    return PyObject_Call((PyObject*)&PyFile_Type, args, kwds);
}
```

- `file.__init__` would open the file
- `file.__enter__` indeed do nothing except doing empty check on field `file.fp`
- `file.__exit__` invoke `close()` method to close file

**For Question 2**

Why `file` design like this is due to a historical reason.

**open** and **with** are two different keywords introduced on different versions of CPython. **with** was introduced till Python 2.5 (see [PEP 343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)). At that time, **open** has been used for a long time.

For our customized type, we could design like **file** or not, depends on the concrete application context.

For example, **threading.Lock** is a different design, its **init** and **enter** are separately.